# Tapestry Framework Need help to case bytea SQL

Tags: postgresql, tapestry

Here is my problem:
my SQL:

```
SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt(password_confirm::bytea, (select setting_value from act_setting_value where setting_value_id= 10007 and setting_value_key = 'pgp_key' and del_flg ='0')) as password FROM ACT_EMP_MST WHERE del_flg = '0' AND emp_no= ?
```

when I create SQL using Tapestry framework, the system create sql like this:

```
SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt(password_confirm:?, (select setting_value from act_setting_value where setting_value_id= 10007 and setting_value_key = 'pgp_key' and del_flg ='0')) as password FROM ACT_EMP_MST WHERE del_flg = '0' AND emp_no= ?
```

In postgresql, I have function name pgp_sym_decrypt, but tapestry not recognize :bytea so tapestry replace :bytea with ? . With :bytea replace with ?, postgresql cannot run the function.
Anyone have the solution ?
I am using Tapestry ver 5.3 and postgresql. 
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Found the solutions: cast(password_confirm as bytea)